# How do i set Time as high score?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, time, save, autosave

im creating a simple game which the objective is to deliver items the fastest as you can.There are no other score points except time, i manage to make the time start as the game begin and stop when the objective is done, but how do i save the time when it stop and make it appear at the home page as the "Best Time"? for now im still using other score points with the time, but im going to delete it and use only Time instead, help me, thanks in advance :)

these are several codes where i manage to stop the time, just write it here in case if it is needed, will write other codes as well if needed.

```
if (score==15) {
    time1.stop();
    gotoAndPlay('resultframe')
```

---

```
stop();
    time1.stop();
    score2_txt.text = String(score);
    timeField2.text = String(""+minute+":"+second+"");
    response_txt.text = "Well Done! You won!";
```

---

```
var minute = 5;
    var second = 59;
    var time1:Timer = new Timer (1000);

 time1.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, calcTime);
 function calcTime(e:TimerEvent):void {

second -= 1;
if(second == 00){
minute -= 1;
second = 59;
}
timeField.text = String(""+minute+":"+second+"");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import flash.utils.getTimer;
var startTime:int;

function chronometerStart():void
{
    startTime = getTimer();
}
function chronometerStop():int
{
    var now:int = getTimer();
    var time:int = now - startTime;
    return time;
}
```

the **`getTimer()`**-method returns the number of milliseconds that have elapsed since the swf gegan to run. 
*Greetings André*

Comment: hi Andre, can you elaborate more on how do i use those code u write? should i replace any of mine or just add it at somewhere or within mine?

Comment: At starting the game you call 'chronometerStart'. At game over you assign a var to 'chronometerStop()' -> `var msec:int=chronometerStop()` this 'msec' you have to compute to your wanted timeFormat and bring it to your textfields/highscore-save-method or whatever.

Comment: Did you figure it out?